# Проверить строку на наличие другой строки java 8

Tags: java, строки, list

Всем привет, хочу проверить лист строк так, чтобы если в каждом элементе массива была строка "New York" - переменная типа boolean возвращала true.

```
Boolean checkForCity = searchingPage.listAdresses.stream().allMatch("New York"::contains);
```

В любом случае переменная checkForCity возвращает false, при том, что каждая трока имеет это сочетание слов

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Вам не подошёл ни один из ответов, данных на ваши предыдущие вопросы, или вы сознательно игнорируете правила ресурса и не [отмечаете решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: да, не помагают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код `allMatch("New York"::contains)` означает, что все элементы листа должны содержаться в строке `"New York"`. А Вам надо наоборот - `allMatch((str) -> str.contains("New York"))`.

Comment: спасибо, это помогло

Answer (score 0):

Сделаю еще одну попытку в стиле Java 8:

```
 String[] strings={"New York", "New Yorker", "new"};
 boolean checkForCity=(stream.filter(line->!line.contains("New York")).count())>0?false:true;
```